# Akka HTTP using a response unmarshaller

Tags: java, akka-http, akka-stream

I'm constructing a data pipeline using Akka streams and Akka HTTP. The use case is quite simple, receive a web request from a user which will do two things. First create a session by calling a 3rd party API, secondly committing this session to some persistent storage, when we have received the session it will then proxy the original user request but add the session data.

I have started working on the first branch of the data pipeline which is the session processing but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of unmarshalling the HTTP response from the 3rd party API to a POJO currently I'm using `Jackson.unmarshaller.unmarshal` which returns a `CompletionStage<T>` which I then have to unwrap into `T`. It's not very elegant and I'm guessing that Akka HTTP has more clever ways of doing this.

Here is the code I have right now

```
private final Source<Session, NotUsed> session =
        Source.fromCompletionStage(
                getHttp().singleRequest(getSessionRequest(), getMat())).
                map(r -> Jackson.unmarshaller(Session.class).unmarshal(r.entity(), getMat())).
                map(f -> f.toCompletableFuture().get()).
                alsoTo(storeSession);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka Streams offers you `mapAsync`, a stage to handle asynchronous computation in your pipeline in a configurable, non-blocking way.

Your code should become something like

```
Source.fromCompletionStage(
                getHttp().singleRequest(getSessionRequest(), getMat())).
                mapAsync(4, r -> Jackson.unmarshaller(Session.class).unmarshal(r.entity(), getMat())).
                alsoTo(storeSession);
```

Note that:

1. it is not just a matter of elegance in this case, as `CompletableFuture.get` is a blocking call. This can cause dreadful issues in your pipeline.
2. the `Int` parameter required by `mapAsync` (parallelism) allows for fine-tuning of how many parallel async operations can be run at the same time.

More info in `mapAsync` can be found in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.1/java/stream/stages-overview.html#mapAsync).

Comment: That's very neat, I was hoping that there would be something even more high level used by Akka HTTP though, something like `Flow<HttpResponse, T, ?`>` that I could plug into my pipeline that would have been even better.

Comment: On the issue of blocking calls, will it really be so bad in this case though? I was under the impression that the actual pipeline would be executed on the actor thread anyhow so it won't be blocking the running thread.

Comment: Problem is, by default, there is no such thing as "the actor thread". Blocking inside an actor will starve the whole threading infrastructure shared by your actor system. Whenever this is unavoidable (e.g. when dealing with blocking-IO) you can setup your pipeline stage to use a separate threadpool. In this case there's no need for that. More info here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/actor-systems.html#Blocking_Needs_Careful_Management .